# how to play video on splash after loding default image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

i want to play video of 4 second in app after default black image is launched what can i do? please help me

my code is below

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

    NSString* moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro_anim" ofType:@"mov"];

    NSURL* movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    NSLog(@"%@",movieURL );

    playerCtrl =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    [playerCtrl prepareToPlay];

    playerCtrl.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

    playerCtrl.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    playerCtrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);

    [playerCtrl.view setCenter:CGPointMake(240, 160)];

    [playerCtrl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)

                                                   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];


    [playerCtrl play];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerCtrl.view];

    [self.view addSubview:playerCtrl.view];

}
```

Comment: this one : `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerCtrl.view];`
wouldn't work because it's not MPMoviePlayerViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    NSString *url;

UIButton *btnvideo;

UIButton *btnaudio;

MPMoviePlayerController *player;

MPMoviePlayerController *Player;

NSArray *arr;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btnvideo;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btnaudio;

-(void) moviefinished:(NSNotification *)anotification;

-(void) Audiofinished:(NSNotification *)bnotification;

-(IBAction)PlayAudio:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)PlayVideo:(id)sender;


#import "ViewController.h"

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

-(IBAction)PlayVideo:(id)sender

{
     url=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"nfc" ofType:@"mp4"];

 player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

 player.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300); 

 [self.view addSubview:player.view];

 [player play];

}

-(IBAction)PlayAudio:(id)sender

{  
        [player release];

    url=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"bgm" ofType:@"mp3"];

    Player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL      fileURLWithPath:url]];

  Player.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300); 

 [self.view addSubview:Player.view];

[Player play];
}
-(void) moviefinished:(NSNotification *)anotification

{
       player=[anotification object];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

  [player autorelease];  

}

-(void) Audiofinished:(NSNotification *)bnotification

{
    player=[bnotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:Player];

[Player autorelease];  

}
-(void)presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:(MPMoviePlayerViewController *)moviePlayerViewController

{
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];

}
```

**Note-** please mind it to connect playaudio button action to

Comment: I think it fulfilled your answer

Answer (score 0):

Insted of a default image use a view controller as splash and push the "first viewcontroller" using timer. You can do whatever you want on your "splash view controller."